# .Net Core NUnit Test project couldn't read value from appconfig.json file with CopyToOutputDirectory

Tags: c#, .net-core

I have a NUnit test project and I've created config file (appconfig.json) and got the Copy to Output Directory set:
[image]

Checked .csproj:

```
  <Content Include="Properties/appconfig.json">
    <CopyToOutputDirectory>Always</CopyToOutputDirectory>
  </Content>
  <Content Include="Properties/launchSettings.json">
    <CopyToOutputDirectory>Always</CopyToOutputDirectory>
  </Content>
</ItemGroup>
```

Then I created a ConfigReader class to get the configs from appconfig.json file:

```
public class ConfigReader
    {
        public static string GetSetting(string key)
        {
            IConfiguration configuration = new ConfigurationBuilder().AddJsonFile("appconfig.json", true, true).Build();
            return configuration["Config:" + key].ToString();
        }
    }
```

And I always got the error like:

> System.NullReferenceException: 'Object reference not set to an
> instance of an object.'
> Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.IConfiguration.this[string].get
> returned null.

Could anyone please help me to fix this? Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

You need to manually update your csproj to preserve latest I believe. I can confirm this tomorrow morning as I had the exact same issue. It's something with the csproj file.

Comment: Hi @ktbffh, you mean I need to add all the config values to csproj manually? I'm using netcoreapp3.1 btw

Comment: @HCYH your answer isn't the correct one - you shouldn't need to add it. When you recompile, you might to maintain it. Try doing this  

<CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out. Need to put the config file to the debug folder manually.

Comment: This is not correct - the bin is binaries generated at compile time. You need to set the file to also make sure it compiles (could be preserve newest so anytime the file changes and you compile, it will update). You shouldn't be manually putting the file into the bin folder because that means you'd be doing it for every launch if the file changes.

Answer (score 0):

If running in Debug mode, the following subfolder is where the configuration file is copied/replaced to when the CopyToOutputDirectory property is set to Always or PreserveNewest:

```
\bin\Debug\netcoreapp3.1\
```

If you set the CopyToOutputDirectory option to Always, then the configuration file will ALWAYS copy the configuration file from the project folder into the output folder.

If you set the CopyToOutputDirectory option to PreserveNewest, then the configuration file will replace the configuration file from the output folder with the configuration from the project folder if the timestamp of the configuration file in the project folder is newer, else it will not replace the configuration file in the output
folder.

This is how it has worked for me.